# Configure an Windows 10 host to acquire IPv6 using stateless DHCPv6 despites router configured as statefull

Tags: windows, ipv6, windows-10

I have one home router that provides no advanced configuration option for IPv6 DHCP (only a checkbox IPv6 enable/disable, so I cannot configure it to use stateless dhcp). The default behavior of an Windows 10 host in the network is to acquire two GUA IPv6: one from the the DHCP server full state and another from SLAAC. But I would like to have only one GUA IPv6 in the host, acquired as DHCPv6 stateless. Is it possible? Using help from netsh, I was not able to find a solution (but I was able to do that in a Debian host).

Comment: DHCP is not stateless. Study the router advertisements and their flags. If no host on the net is to use DHCP, have the RA managed bit not set.  And get a better router.

Comment: Stateless DHCPv6 is defined by RFC 3936, check for example https://www.networkacademy.io/ccna/ipv6/stateless-dhcpv6